# C++ Using Getline

Tags: c++, getline

I am creating an address book program and I'm having trouble properly reading the file. Its only reading the information from the first person in the file and it has an infinite loop. I know there is a problem with my GetRecord function. Any suggestions on how I can fix my code would be greatly appreciated.

Test file

```
Susan, Smith, (123) 456-7890
101 Main Street
Bob, King, (567) 345-9076
456 Market Street
```

Program Code

```
void SearchFirstName(ifstream& inData)
{
    Person p;

    string firstName, lastName, phone, address;

    cout << "Enter the first name of the person: ";
    cin >> p.firstname;

    string upperFirst = NormalizeString(p.firstname);
    string upperSearchFirst = NormalizeString(firstName);
    while (GetRecord(inData, firstName, lastName, phone, address))
    {

        if (upperFirst == upperSearchFirst)
        break;

       if(inData){
        cout << "Person found: " << endl;
        PrintRecord(firstName,lastName, phone, address);
    }
    else
    {
    cout << p.firstname << " not found!" << endl << endl;
    }

    inData.clear();
    inData.seekg(0);
  }
 }


bool GetRecord(ifstream& inData,
           string& firstName, string& lastName,
           string& phone, string& address) 
{
    getline(inData, firstName, ',');

    getline(inData, lastName, ',');

    getline(inData, phone, '\n');

    getline(inData, address);
    return inData;

 }

void PrintRecord(string firstName, string lastName,string phone, string address)
 {
     cout << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
     cout << "Phone: " << phone << endl;
     cout << "Address: " << address << endl;
 }
```

Output Should Be:
If user searches by first name and types in bob

```
Person found:
Name: Bob King
Phone: (567) 345-9076
456 Market Street
```

Comment: Mention your problem! Or expected output?

Comment: @MohammadTayyab I mentioned my problem in my question. If the user decides to search by first name and enters 'bob' it outputs an infinite loop of "Susan Smith" information instead of Bob's. Do I need to edit my question to include more of my code?

Comment: If you'll add more code, Maybe I can provide a better solution.

Comment: @MohammadTayyab I added my searchFirstName and Print functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have some of your classes and functions, so i commented extra code. You can apply this method easily on your code. It will work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void GetRecord(ifstream& inData,
    string& firstName, string& lastName,
    string& phone, string& address)
{
    getline(inData, firstName, ',');

    getline(inData, lastName, ',');

    getline(inData, phone, '\n');

    getline(inData, address);
}

void PrintRecord(string firstName, string lastName, string phone, string address)
{
    cout << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
    cout << "Phone: " << phone << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << address << endl;
}
void SearchFirstName(ifstream& inData)
{
    string firstName, firstname, lastName, phone, address;
    cout << "Enter the first name of the person: ";
    cin >> firstname;
    bool flag = false;
    //string upperFirst = NormalizeString(p.firstname);
    //string upperSearchFirst = NormalizeString(firstName);
    while (!inData.eof())
    {
        GetRecord(inData, firstName, lastName, phone, address);
        //if (upperFirst == upperSearchFirst)
            //break;
        if (firstName == firstname)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        if (flag){
            cout << "Person found: " << endl;
            PrintRecord(firstName,lastName,phone,address);
        }
    }
    if (!flag)
    {
        cout << "RECORD NOT FOUND";
    }
}
int main()
{
    ifstream in("File.txt");
    SearchFirstName(in);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```